# How can I further develop this warrior fantasy story of mine?

Tags: creative-writing, character-development, fantasy, world-building, plot-structure

My fantasy story is about an 18-year old knight who was trained from 5-years old to 18-years old as a knight. He is an expert when it comes to using a two-handed double-edged longsword as a weapon. He is also an expert when it comes to empty-handed martial arts such as ones that involve punching, etc. Currently, he is continuously training as a knight in order to be the best warrior he can be in his whole life. Age 15 was the age he began fighting in battles. He also frequently hunted and killed dangerous criminals(such as bandits, street gang members, pirates, etc.) in villages and in city streets. There were evil knights that often challenged him to duels to the death and he defeated and killed all of the evil knights that challenged him. He also defeated many criminals, invader imperialist emperors, barbarian savages, terrorists, etc. when it comes to duels to the death. He was one of the best martial artists and individual warriors in the entire world. He hopes to retire as a knight at the age of 40.

This 18-year old knight is a nice person. From the time he was born to his current age, he never bullied people physically, emotionally, and verbally. He hates the idea of committing immoral deeds such as theft, rape, pimping, murder, etc. He hated gangsters, brutal imperialist conquerors, brutal uncivilized barbarians, and terrorists very much. This is why he loves being a brutal vigilante towards criminals such as bandits, pirates, street gang members, etc. He often captures criminals(such as bandits, pirates, street gang members, etc.) alive and brutally tortures them to death.

My story is set in a world where various nations are brutally conquering each other. In this world, demons and vampires are widespread all over the world that they present so much threat to humanity.

Also, the 18-year old knight doesn't want to get married. He wants to be single and virgin forever. But his 40-year old father wants him to marry and have children. His father was somehow a bad person because he pressures the 18-year old knight to marry and have children by saying to the 18-year old boy that he will have him killed if he didn't marry and have children. The 18-year old knight's father is a very powerful political person in the government. The 18-year old knight's father is also a very skilled and very respected military commander in the military of the nation where the 18-year old knight is from. The 18-year old knight's father uses his political power in order to pressure the 18-year old knight to marry and have kids.

The 18-year old knight's father doesn't just pressure the 18-year old boy into marrying and having kids. He also pressures the boy into how many he should marry and who are the ones he should marry. The 18-year old knight's father wants his son to marry a group of 30 sacred temple warrior maidens and have kids with all of them. He pressures the 18-year old boy to do this by threatening him with death. The 18-year old knight said to his father that marrying more than one wife and having more than 3 kids is too much for him but his father was persistent on him marrying all of the 30 sacred temple warrior maidens and him having children with all of them to the point that the 18-year old knight can't do anything to go against his father's wishes.

The group of 30 females that the knight boy is forced to marry are very skilled warriors when it comes to protecting sacred temples and their nation. Sacred temple warrior maidens are not part of the military of the nation that the 18-year old knight is from but they act as a sort of special elite warriors for their nation in some times. They are special elite warriors because they possess battle skills that are exclusive to them and they are one of the best groups of warriors in their nation. Sacred temple warrior maidens are basically females. Aside from being warriors, they are also dutiful servants of sacred temples. They also engage in exorcism against evil spirits as well as spreading religious messages in sacred temples towards common religious people who are temple goers.

Normally, sacred temple warrior maidens are virgins who do not marry, have lovers, have kids, or have sex but they are allowed to. Once they marry, have lovers, have kids, have sex, or all of these acts, they are no longer allowed to be sacred temple warrior maidens. Sacred temple warrior maidens must always be virgins.

The 30 females that the 18-year old knight boy is forced to marry eventually decided that they want to marry and have kids. They don't want to be sacred warrior temple maidens anymore. All of them want to marry the 18-year old knight boy and have kids with him so they all agreed to the decision that they will share him together. No one knows why they like the 18-year old boy. Anyways, polygamy is normal and legal in the culture that the 18-year old knight boy is from. In his culture, only rich males practice polygamy but the 18-year old boy is not rich so he is kind of angry towards his father for forcing him to marry all of the 30 sacred temple warrior maidens. Eventually, he is forced to find a way to get a job that will make him rich.

The group of 30 sacred temple warrior maidens that the 18-year old knight is forced to marry are platonic friends toward each other because they have been friends with each other since they were below the age of 11. They were raised to be sacred temple warrior maidens since they were below the age of 11. They are nice people in that they do not commit immoral acts.

In the end, the 18-year old knight boy married all of the 30 sacred temple warrior maidens. By the way, no one forced the 30 sacred warrior maidens to marry the 18-year old knight boy or have kids with him. All of the 30 sacred warrior maidens were virgins when the 18-year old knight boy married them.

When the knight boy married all of the 30 females, the age range of the 30 females were from 18 to 22. In this group of 30 females, there are:

- 7 eighteen year olds
- 5 nineteen year olds
- 7 twenty year olds
- 5 twenty one year olds
- 6 twenty two year olds

There are also females who are a bit taller than the 18-year old knight boy and these are them:

- 3 of the eighteen year olds
- 1 of the nineteen year olds
- 3 of the twenty year olds
- 1 of the twenty one year olds
- 2 of the twenty two year olds

The rest of the 30 sacred temple warrior maidens are the same height as the 18-year old knight boy.

The relationship of the knight boy towards his 30 wives(who are former sacred temple warrior maidens) is fine. He was forced to marry all of the 30 females but he began to like and love all of them in the end. All of his 30 wives are submissive and loyal to him. They do household chores for him like cooking, etc. Before the 30 females became pregnant, all of the knight boy's 30 wives are addicted to having sex with the knight boy which is why they demanded that he always have sex with each of them. The knight boy was forced to comply so he always had sex with all of them. After that, each of his 30 wives demanded to him that he should have children with each of them which resulted in the knight boy's 30 wives having enlarged pregnant bellies.

When the 30 wives of the knight boy were still sacred temple warrior maidens, they all wore the same dress and that is a long elegant sacred dress but after they stopped being sacred temple warrior maidens, they started becoming individualistic in their clothing so they wore different clothes.

Then they all started wearing the same specific combination of clothes and that combination is made up of:

1. A buttoned dark-blue feminine lightweight blazer.
2. A buttoned light-blue blouse.
3. A light-brown long skirt. The long skirt's bottom edge reaches the ankles of the 30 females. The long skirt is not pleated. The long skirt is soft and relaxed which means it does not gradually widen from the waist to the bottom edge. The long skirt is straight which means it does not gradually widen from the waist to the bottom edge.
4. A pair of short pure-white socks that never reaches the upper halves of the 30 females' lower legs(the legs below the 30 females' thighs).
5. A pair of dark-brown shoes.

The knight boy always gets turned on when his 30 wives are wearing this same specific combination of clothes while the buttoned dark-blue feminine lightweight blazers of the 30 females are unbuttoned and his 30 wives have enlarged pregnant bellies due to him impregnating all of them. He always loves to hug his 30 wives' enlarged pregnant bellies. When the 30 females are wearing this same specific combination of clothes, the buttoned dark-blue feminine lightweight blazers of the 30 females are unbuttoned most of the time.

This same specific combination of clothes did not come from the knight boy because it was the idea of his 30 wives. Before the 30 females wore this same specific combination of clothes, they were individualistic in what they wear which means that they wore clothes that are different from each others'. Many people and the knight boy then felt weird about the knight boy's 30 wives beginning to wear this same specific combination of clothes. Eventually, many people and the knight boy realized that the knight boy's 30 wives made the idea of this same specific combination of clothes as a symbol of their wifehood and femininity towards the knight boy. Many people and the knight boy also realized that for the 30 females, this same specific combination of clothes was also a symbol of the sisterhood that the 30 females have for each other. The knight boy was confused by all of these at the start but he liked all of it in the end.

By the way, none of the 30 females are wearing objects that tie their hairs or are on their hairs. Their hairs are all free and relaxed which means their hairs are straight due to their hairs being naturally straight. Also, none of the females are wearing make-up. Also, none of the females have nails that are painted.

As for the biological looks of all of the knight's 30 wives, these are their characteristics:

1. All of them have long straight deep-dark-brown hairs but each of their hairs have small differences with each other.
2. All of them have pale skin.
3. Many of them have different eye pupil colors from each other.
4. All of them are physically fit. None of them are fat or overly thin.
5. All of them have the same body shape.
6. All of them are tall.
7. All of them are in good shape.

This is the combination of clothes that the knight boy wears in times when he is just a civilian and not in service as a knight:

1. A pure-white lightweight hoodless jacket.
2. A pure-white T-shirt.
3. Pants. The color of the pants is light-grey.
4. A pair of short pure-white socks that never reaches the upper halves of his lower legs(the legs below his thighs).
5. A pair of pure-white shoes.
6. A pair of pure-white thin gloves.

As for his biological appearance, here are his characteristics:

1. His hair is short and black. His hair is short to the point that it never reaches his shoulders.
2. He has pale skin.
3. He is tall.
4. He is muscular.
5. He is physically fit.
6. He is in good shape.

The knight boy and his 30 wives live in a village. In the village, he hunts and kills vampires and demons that try to harm his 30 wives, the babies in his 30 wives' pregnant bellies, and other innocent people.

So what do you think of this warrior fantasy story of mine? How can I further develop this? What should I add? What mistakes does it have?

Comment: I think you may be focusing too much on the descriptions than your actual question here. I didn't read the whole thing, but it sounded like almost or over half of your question was you going into unnecessary detail about how the women were clothed. I don't think this is bad, but a waste of space and could potentially deter people from reading on, causing them to miss important details. Consider consolidating consorts.

Answer (score 6):

I think your story is one dimensional; you have your hero, he's great, has many wives, kills bad guys, ... and that's it. In writing it is called a "Mary Sue" story; a fantasy fulfillment of the author in which the protagonist never makes a mistake and gets everything he wants. They are boring stories, for everybody except the author.

To be a good story it requires some sort of protagonist struggle, a challenge they cannot meet, and when they are done, they have some personal growth; new knowledge; a better understanding of **life**, or some **empathy** they did not have before, or **love** they did not have before.

You can cover all this super-competent expertise in the first 25% of the story. And it is fine if your protagonist feels that is all there is to life! It is better, in fact, because after the first 25%, you are going to put him in the cooker.

You need to give your knight a problem where all his expertise in battle and fighting and strategy **will not do him a damn bit of good.**

A problem where physical fighting **doesn't work,** and possibly there isn't even a physical villain to battle!

I'd suggest a mental puzzle, something that requires the fighter to **think** and **learn** things they have never bothered to learn or think about. Perhaps a strategic problem, or finding a traitor that is smarter than him.

In a good story, the hero is kicked in the face, dragged by horses, thrown off a cliff, and they keep getting back up, broken, bloody, even defeated, but they would rather **die** than give up. **That is what makes them a hero.**

Not fighting better than everyone else, or screwing more than everyone else, or having more wealth or children or property than everyone else. They are heroic because even after they have lost everything, even when they are limping, injured and bloody, even when they themselves don't believe they can win, they still **get back up and fight some more.**

I stopped reading your synopsis half way through. Your hero is not really struggling with anything. A few disagreements with daddy or the wives is not going to break him. You need to invent a problem for him to solve that the readers believe has a good chance to *break* him, despite all his expertise with a sword, with martial arts, with women or whatever.

Your knight needs a weakness, and the story has to be about that weakness, not about how wonderful he is with everything else.

Comment: This answer is really good, not only because it points out the shortcomings, but it provides an answer. I will add, however, that characterization (or characterisation) is another important factor in writing an engaging story; It doesn't feel to me like this "knight boy" is anything more than his label ascribes. Do you want to root for a man, or do you want to root for a loving, single father of three who is struggling against alcoholism after his wife passed away in a car accident?

Comment: By the way, what do you think of the same specific combination of clothes that the knight boy's 30 wives wear? I am not talking about the long elegant sacred dress that the 30 wives used to wear when they were still sacred temple warrior maidens.

Comment: If you really want a comment on the costumes - to me they sound incongruously modern for a story about warrior knights etc. - but the setting is your invention and, as you say, you can do what you like.

Comment: @JamesLange I did not read them. This is not a site for critique of your writing; please understand that. "Opinion questions" are prohibited here and will be closed; that includes asking "what do you think of this?" kinds of questions. This is a site to help you solve fiction problems. We are not here to advise you on the specific creative content or to review your writing samples or provide opinions on your creative choices. "What I think about these clothes" is an opinion question. You could ask "what did wealthy women wear in the middle ages", you would probably get some pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome James to the community. It is a good step towards more creative writing that you shared your story and asking for ideas.

I will share with you my ideas, hoping it would help you go forward with your fantasy story.

**Analyzing your characters**:

1. A child who is trained to be a merciless killer and torturer and carries a fancy title for that "Knight".
2. A corrupted politician and bad parent
3. Thirty unnamed exotic warrior "virgin" girls.

**Time and Environment**:

1. No specific time but seems like medieval because of using swords as weapons and widely believing in magic.
2. A fictional place where vampires, perhaps other monsters, and criminals are everywhere and the whole world is in an open war and conquer state.

Before we go more in details about building your story, **I have important points to share**:

1. Your protagonist is described as

> From the time he was born to his current age, he never bullied people
> physically, emotionally, and verbally. He hates the idea of committing
> immoral deeds such as theft, rape, pimping, murder, etc.

but still he does

> He often captures criminals(such as bandits, pirates, street gang
> members, etc.) alive and brutally tortures them to death.

My point is you cannot have your character both good and brutally tortures to death. Unless, he has psychological illness and you will share that through the story.

2. There is no entirely good or entirely evil character and there is no action without motives.
3. What is the motive behind the disagreeing of the knight with his father on marrying that big number of warrior beautiful girls in a society considering that polygamy is a privilege.
4. How come that his father is a corrupted politician but still the young knight is poor?
5. Remember that all girls were fertile and pregnant at the same time. This is a coincidence of thirty pregnancies.
6. These warrior girls have more biological details than their backstories and motives.
7. What is the motive of the father for marrying his son to those particular group of temple warriors? Is it a political goal?

**How to improve your current idea**:

1. Look closely at all of your characters and find their motives. Do not get attached to only the protagonist, neglecting every other character.
2. Establish laws and codes of the environment so that the reader can understand who is acting according to the law and who is out of the law.
3. Look closely at the inside-conflict of every character as you already have very good complicated situations. For example (a killer and torturer who is acting nicely and caring, a corrupted politician yet trying to force his "only?" son to the best course according to his life experience, and every girl reaching the same decision for different reasons).

Good luck and I hope you will achieve your goals with your story.

Comment: @JamesLange I have deleted your comments because their tone was completely inappropriate. We have a Code of Conduct here that we expect all contributors to abide by. On a broader level, your question is explicitly asking people to point out the mistakes they think you've made. If you're going to get mad at people for doing so, and say things like "I'm the author and I can make my story whatever I want it to be", then why are you even asking for feedback in the first place?

Comment: Your point about the "Sociopath/hero" two-face problem is potential for a really good conflict: What if this person is, according to his profession and status, considered a hero, not because he tortures people but because he chooses the right people to torture? If he has a mental illness, or is an incredible sadist (they can be exclusive, believe it or not), he might not care that he's torturing bad guys. But, since "bad guys" are the only people society allows, even encourages him to torture, he's made a profession of his pleasure, managing to hide this darker side of him from those he loves.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the plot of an ecchi harem manga.

Treating it as such, I wouldn't worry too much about the usual characteristics of a "good" story. The point here isn't to win a literature prize, it's to entertain other people that like to indulge in these kind of fantasies. (Yes, like Amadeus says, it's "*fantasy fulfillment*", but the author isn't the only one in the world with such fantasies. Embrace the niche *if* this is what you want.)

So, to develop this story, I'd concentrate on what's important. Which is that each of those 30 warrior girls is different and worth falling in love with. There are tons of tropes you can make use of, like the clumsy girl that tries hard, the motherly type that looks out for the rest, the haughty girl that's jealous and vulnerable, etc. (TVTrope's [Moe](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Moe) page is a good place to start if you need inspiration. Or read manga/watch anime.)

One big issue is having this many characters. Making a reader care about just one character takes a while, and doing that for thirty makes it a monumental task. So perhaps for the initial book/volume just concentrate on a handful, so you can get into their backstory and motivation etc (as mentioned in other answers). The rest would be more like background characters for now, until they get to take center stage in later books/volumes.

A few side notes: It's kind of a shame you seem to try to make all these girls look almost the same, because that would make it hard to draw as a manga (it makes it hard to distinguish the characters). A few different hairstyles would go a long way. And if we're speaking manga, then obviously nekomimi and other animal and monster characteristics are an option.

All the girls seem to be as taller or taller than the hero, so maybe the hero is just really short for a guy. That could be a fun weakness that you can play for comedic value. And the hero might be trying to (over)compensate for it by fighting extra hard and taking bigger risks.

Also, instead of the father forcing him to get married with threats of death, you could have him get the hero really drunk. And then the next morning the hero wakes up married next to 30 girls. Because that sounds funnier.

The most important thing is to just have fun. If you have fun writing it, then people that like this sort of thing will also have fun reading it.